# Using Angular JS in a firefox addon

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a firefox addon which displays a div on the top of the page loading json data and showing it in a nice manner. I want to use angular js for that. However it's not working. And I don't know why.

My code so far:

```
var { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var data = require("sdk/self").data; 

var button = ActionButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "Start LLIBrowser",
  icon: {
    "16": "./logo-16.png"
  },
  onClick: showPlugIn
});

function showPlugIn(state){ 
  tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.min.js"),    data.url("contentscript.js")],
    contentScriptOptions: {
        divContent: data.load("overlay.html"),
        angularLib: data.url("angular.min.js"),
        angularApp: data.url("app.js")
    }
});
```

}

```
overlay.html:

<script type="text/javascript" src="resource://LLIBrowser/data/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="resource://LLIBrowser/data/app.js"></script>
<div ng-app="store" style="position:relative; clear:both; zIndex:100;   width:100%; height:150px; background-color:#313192; color:white">

<!--STUFF -->
</div>
```

I'm absolutely helpless here....

Thanks in adavance!

Comment: your code has no controller, do you refer to angularjs demo?

Comment: what is not working?any errors?

Comment: Use relative URLs to your js files, since those resource:// URIs don't look like ones your addon would have.